# "Use `::<...>` instead of `<...>` to specify lifetime, type, or const arguments"

Tags: rust, hashmap

I'm trying to use create a `HashMap` that cointains the largest run (number of consecutively repeated elements)  in a `Vec` named `data`.

For example, if we have `[1,1,3,1,1]` then we should get the `HashMap` like `{1: 2}`

However, I cant seem to figure out why the compiler is complaining about

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: expected one of `!`, `.`, `::`, `;`, `?`, `else`, `{`, or an operator, found `,`
 --> src/main.rs:7:39
  |
7 |   let mut counts = HashMap::HashMap<u8, u8>::new();
  |                                       ^ expected one of 8 possible tokens
  |
help: use `::<...>` instead of `<...>` to specify lifetime, type, or const arguments
  |
7 |   let mut counts = HashMap::HashMap::<u8, u8>::new();
```

Here's my code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp;

fn main() {
  let data: Vec<u8> = vec![1,1,3,1,1];
    
  let mut counts = HashMap::HashMap<u8, u8>::new();
  let mut current_count = 0;
  for (i, &x) in data.iter().enumerate() {
    if i > 0 {
        if x == data[i-1] {
            current_count += 1;
            counts.entry(x).or_insert(cmp::max(current_count, *counts.get(&x).unwrap()));
        } else {
            current_count = 0;
        }
    }
  }
  
  println!("{:?}", counts);
}
```

Comment: DO NOT edit a question to add another question, **especially** when that invalidates existing answers. Ask a new question. I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current error is coming from your initialization of `HashMap`.

`HashMap::HashMap<u8, u8>::new()` is not valid syntax. Since `HashMap::new()` isn't a generic function (it's a non-generic function of a generic data structure), there's no way to specify its type parameters.

Instead, we want to specify the type of `counts` so that the right `new()` function gets called. We can do this explicitly:

```
let mut counts: HashMap<u8, u8> = HashMap::new();
```

But more often than not, Rust's powerful type inference can save you the headache of even having to worry about things like this:

```
let mut counts = HashMap::new();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got another error after fixing the initialization `cannot borrow \`counts\` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable`. Updated the original question

Comment: @gameveloster You can ask a new question.

Comment: "*Since `HashMap::new()` isn't a generic function (it's a non-generic function of a generic data structure), there's no way to specify its type parameters.*"—you can do `<HashMap<u8, u8>>::new()` or (my preference) `HashMap::<u8, u8>::new()`, though I agree that usually `HashMap::new()` alone is fine (because the type parameters can be inferred).  I personally don't like annotating the binding, not sure why (perhaps because it's a bit repetitive).